# Testing to Compare for "Impact" of Independent Variable on Dependent Variable

Tags: multiple-regression, predictor

How can I perform a statistical test to judge impact of an independent variable on a dependent variable given multiple regression output? In the example below, how would I test if gender or work experience has a greater impact on gross pay?

Independent variables: education, work experience
Dependent variable: gross pay

Example (artificial) Multiple regression output:

Predictor      Coefficient    SECoef    T

Constant    1200           .35        3.43

Education   3500           .020        1.75

Work exp.   3000           .012        2.4

I understand that looking at the coefficients should be the first place we can look to determine the affect ind. variables have on the dependent variable. In this case, education would have more of an effect on the dependent variable because its coefficient is larger than the coefficient for work experience. I also realize that the T value of work experience is larger, indicating it is more statistically significant than education.

Is there a better way to gauge which ind. variable has a larger affect on the dependent variable? Perhaps with a CI/hypothesis test?

Comment: I found that a test statistic can be developed to calculate the critical value to use in a hypothesis test. The test statistic = (b1 - b2)/sqrt(se(b1)^2 + se(b2)^2)). This test statistic is valid because in my case the two predicted beta values were independent. If you cannot assume the beta values are independent you must use add the covariance to the sum of squared standard errors in the denominator of the test statistic formula.